# How to rearrange legend order in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting the graph in ggplot. Everything was fine but now I have a problem with the legend. i want to rearrange the legend. The legend that I am getting now is

0-63

100-200

200-400

63-100

what I want is. I want to move the last value to the 2nd position. It should be like that

0-63

63-100

100-200

200-400

my code is below

my data look like this but up to 1000 rows

```
time  less63  63_100    100_200   200_400
06:01   0       4        3           1
06:02   2       6        6           5
06:03   4       8        8           6
06:04   6       9        7           8
06:05   7       10       8           7
06:06   3       11       3           7
06:07   6       7        2           2
06:08   7       3        0           3





ggplot(df)+
      geom_area(aes(x=time,y=less63,fill="0-63"),alpha=0.5)+
      geom_area(aes(x=time,y=63_100,fill="63-100"),alpha=0.5)+
      geom_area(aes(x=time,y=100_200,fill="100-200"),alpha=0.5)+
      geom_area(aes(x=time,y=200_400,fill="200-400"),alpha=0.5)+
      scale_colour_manual(name="Legend", values = c("0-63" = "red","63-100" = "green","100-200" = "black","200-400" = "blue"))
```

I shall be really thankful in this regard

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format?

Comment: I have updated the post. Please check

Comment: Are the times mins:secs or hrs:mins?

Comment: hours and minutes. there are no secounds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you want to do here is put your data into [Tidy Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) format.  Notice how you are specifying a `geom_area()` function for every fill color in your dataset and naming them manually?  The philosophy behind grammar of graphics upon which `ggplot2` was built is that you can use the mapping function `aes()` to let `ggplot2` define the separation and how `fill=` is applied by the observations in your dataset.  We'll do that here, then demonstrate a few other things that will get your plot working... as well as finally making your legend in the proper order.

#### Tidying the Data

To tidy the data, you need to gather the columns except for time into 2 new columns: one to specify the range (i.e. "0-63" or "100-200") which will be mapped to the fill aesthetic, and one to specify the value that will be mapped to the y aesthetic.  As the data stands in `df_original`, you have the values spread across multiple columns (they should be in one column) and the names of those columns should really be gathered into a separate column.  The result of doing this is called "gathering" or making your data "long".

Here, we'll use `pivot_longer()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(scales)

df_original <- read.table(text="time  less63  63_100    100_200   200_400
06:01   0       4        3           1
06:02   2       6        6           5
06:03   4       8        8           6
06:04   6       9        7           8
06:05   7       10       8           7
06:06   3       11       3           7
06:07   6       7        2           2
06:08   7       3        0           3", header=TRUE)

df <- df_original %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -time,   # take everything except time column
    names_to = "ranges",
    values_to = "val"
  ) %>%
  mutate(ranges = factor(
    ranges,
    levels=c("less63", "X63_100", "X100_200", "X200_400"),
    labels=c("0-63", "63-100", "100-200", "200-400")))
```

Then you want to change the `df$range` column to a factor.  Here you can specify the order of the ranges using the `levels=` argument, and while we're at it you can specify how they look (renaming) by the `labels=` argument:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(ranges = factor(
    ranges,
    levels=c("less63", "X63_100", "X100_200", "X200_400"),
    labels=c("0-63", "63-100", "100-200", "200-400")))
```

The last step is converting your `df$time` column to a `POSIXct` object, which means we can reference it as a time object.  You can look at the help for `strptime()` to see what the string for `format=` is referencing:

```
# OP states time is in hours:minutes, so reflected here
df$time <- as.POSIXct(df$time, format="%H:%M")
```

#### Plotting

Plotting is pretty simple now.  Since we tidied up the data, we can just use one `geom_area()` call.  Also, we reordered the factor levels for range, so the order of objects in the legend is set the way it should be and looks the way it should be thanks to the `labels=` argument.

One more thing: you need to reference `scale_fill_manual()` not `scale_colour_manual()`, since the aesthetic that is mapped in `geom_area()` is the fill:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=val, fill=ranges)) +
  geom_area(alpha=0.5) +
  scale_x_time(labels = scales::time_format(format = "%H:%M")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Legend", values = c("0-63" = "red","63-100" = "green","100-200" = "black","200-400" = "blue"))
```

[image]

#### Update: Overlapping Plot

The OP indicated they were creating an overlapping plot.  By default, the position of the layers mapped to fill in `geom_are()` is set to "stacked", which means the y values are stacked on top of one another.  This makes it easy to view and see the way the areas change over the x axis.  However, OP wanted to prepare a plot where the y values are... the value.  This would be `position="identity"` and creates overlapping areas.  You can see the direct effect here:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=val, fill=ranges)) +
  geom_area(alpha=0.2, position="identity") +
  scale_x_time(labels = scales::time_format(format = "%M:%S")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Legend", values = c("0-63" = "red","63-100" = "green","100-200" = "black","200-400" = "blue"))
```

[image]

You can see that even cutting down the `alpha=` value, this is going to be hard to discern what's going on.  If you want to see this information more clearly, I would recommend using horizontally-placed facets as a better viewing option:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=val, fill=ranges)) +
  geom_area(alpha=0.2, position="identity") +
  scale_x_time(labels = scales::time_format(format = "%M:%S")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Legend", values = c("0-63" = "red","63-100" = "green","100-200" = "black","200-400" = "blue")) +
  facet_grid(ranges ~ .)
```

[image]

Comment: Upvote but see the [OP's answer to my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70815344/how-to-rearrange-legend-order-in-ggplot?noredirect=1#comment125191384_70815344). And change the format string in `scales::time_format(format = "%M:%S"))`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I've fixed it to match (no difference in plot appearance though, but "correct" in the backend, so all is now right with the world :)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed solution. but if you see, there is still a problem with y-axis. my graph is an overlapping graph. if I see values at y axis. it's different than the sample data. could you make with overlapping? not stacking one

Comment: ok - give me a min - I'll fix :)

Comment: highly appreciated. well explained. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using tidyr::pivot_longer() on your data so that it looks like this.

time variable value
1 06:01   less63     0
2 06:01   63_100     4

etc...

Then use ordered() to set "variable" as an ordered factor.
Then use geom_area(aes(x = time, y = variable, full = variable)

Comment: Could you explain more in terms of code? I have no experience with tidyr.

Answer (score 1):

1. Bring your data in long format with `pivot_longer`
2. transform `name` to factor (level and label it)
3. In ggplot use `fill` and `group`

**Custom OP:**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -time
  ) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("less63", "X63_100", "X100_200", "X200_400"),
                       labels = c("0-63","63-100","100-200","200-400"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(time), y=value, fill=name, group=name))+
  geom_area(position = "identity", alpha=0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Legend", values = c("0-63" = "red","63-100" = "green","100-200" = "black","200-400" = "blue"))
```

[image]
General approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -time
  ) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = c("less63", "X63_100", "X100_200", "X200_400"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=time, y=value, fill=name, group=name))+
  geom_area()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed solution. but if you see, there is still a problem with y-axis. my graph is an overlapping graph. if I see values at y axis. it's different than the sample data. could you make it with overlapping? not stacking one

Comment: Please see my update: `position="identity` should do it.

Comment: highly appreciated. Thanks :)